# How to grep with filename highlighted in one color, and the match highlighted in another color?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

On the Mac, I can't seem to use `grep` and have the filename highlighted (or in) a certain color, and have the matching string in a different color.  Is there an easy way?

Answer (score 4):

OS X grep is too outdated: it does not support this.

You need to install a newer version, for example from HomeBrew

```
brew install grep
```

By default, the newly installed grep is called `ggrep`.
You can change this behavior by adding the option `--with-default-names`.

For more information, see https://superuser.com/a/419527.

Answer (score 4):

Pipe your grep through `awk`, then have `awk` color the fields.

Example:

```
grep -i "stuff" * | awk -F: '{ printf "\033[1;31m" $1 " \033[0m"; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){out=out":"$i}; print out}'
```

Comment: It's not perfect, but I used an example I found elsewhere and modified it so that awk makes what it thinks is the second field of date's output red:

    date | awk -F: '{ print $1 " \033[1;31m:" $2 "\033[0m" $3 } '

Answer (score 1):

This is already answered on stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236005/grep-output-with-multiple-colors

but it only works if you can match the filenames using a pattern or several patterns.

Comment: can you give a workable answer?

Comment: Not without better understanding what you're trying to match on. The answer I linked to is all the information you'd need, but if you want a copy and paste solution I'm not sure how I feel about doing that leg work without any form of compensation

Answer (score 0):

Using gnu grep with the option `--color=auto` I got both colored search term and file name. For example:

```bsh
ggrep --color=auto -r 'searchKeyWord'
```

If you want to always get this behavior you can add an alias in `~/.bash_profile`

```bsh
alias grep="ggrep --color=auto"
```

And use the grep command as usual

```bsh
grep -r 'searchKeyWord'
```

To install gnu grep check @Fabrice answer.